# Exclusive lock on file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an MSI that was authored using WiX. It installs a VSTO office addin. With an office application running (and thus the addin loaded)  instead of a FilesInUse dialog with   retry, ignore, cancel  I only get a retry and cancel. The installer log shows a 1306 then a 1603 error.  In interactive mode InstallValidate says there's an exclusive lock on this file.    The installer seems incapable of overwriting this file via delayed reboot.

I've set MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL to Disable for testing purposes.   Eventually this will be called by a burn exe  but I'm trying to get my head around the root issues first.   Currently burn displays the retry/cancel dialog and if I run it with /passive /norestart it just tries to install the MSI 4 times and then fails.

The interactive experience isn't too horrible (close the app dummy!)  but the silent experience fails and doesn't do the force install /reboot that I normally see.

What important trivia am I not remembering?

Update: I set MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL back to it's default and set MSIRMSHUTDOWN to 1 and this has fixed all the silent MSI installation scenarios.  However when I have WiX Burn run it as an MsiPackage it fails. I think it's because Burn is passing MSIFASTINSTALL=7 which skips some of the costing steps.   I tried adding MSIFASTINSTALL=0 but I see both getting passed to the MSI and the behavior doesn't change.